# Is there a way to track the status of 100 concurrent lambda functions and send email on successful execution of all the lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

PROBLEM: We are iterating over list of items and for each item, we are pushing messages into SQS where we have lambda trigger. Suppose, we have a 100 items and we are sending 100 messages into the SQS. The, 100 concurrent lambda functions will be executed( and lambda have concurrency set to 50). Now, We need to send a email when all these 100 lambda functions executed successfully. Is there a way in AWS where we can monitor these 100 lambda function status?

I have few ideas, where we can create a separate row in db for each item and mark status as completed after each lambda successful execution. And, then at the end of every lambda function, we can check if we have all 100 entries in db with status completed, then we can send email.

**EDIT:**
Or, we can have step function where parent task can have dynamic parallel states including all child lambda functions using state machine map state. Then, at the next step, we can send the consolidate email.

Please, let me know your thoughts. That would be very helpful

Comment: Or, just check whether the Amazon SQS queue is empty.

Comment: I would use a separate lambda function to monitor completion to avoid the chance that multiple worker functions detect completion and each send an e-mail.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein In this case, I am only worried about race condition. If last 2 lambda function invocations running parallel and then, at the end of both the lambdas, If we check SQS is empty, it will tell us 2 messages in flight means SQS is not empty and there is no next lambda so we can miss sending email. Please correct me if I am wrong
edit: I just realised race condition can happen in database approach as well

Comment: CloudWatch has a `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric to count the number of messages 'not yet processed', and another called `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible` that count the number of messages being processed. Due to the distributed nature of SQS, these are 'approximate' measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case where [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) [Distributed Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html) would help. I'm not sure how you are doing your original iteration, but you could replace that with iteration using Distributed Map. If the list you are iterating over is in S3 already, they you get that out of the box. If it's elsewhere (e.g., in DynamoDB) then you'd need to add a step to either read that list in (if it's less than 256 kB in size, this can be passed in as state input) or write it to S3 first to iterate over (can be in JSON or CSV).

With this, you can then define a workflow to run for each of the items, including calling your Lambda functions. And then when the Distributed Map state completes, you can add in any subsequent steps like sending an email or emitting events to EventBridge.

To learn more about Distributed Map, you can read the docs linked above and check out [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) or [this session from re:Invent 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SG6_oy72hh4).